How to Access Real-Time Data from Local Storage Files in Browser Directory?
I’m monitoring a website where news updates are displayed in real-time. I can see these updates in the LocalStorage section of my browser's Developer Tools (under example.com/news).
I’m wondering where the data is being stored, if it's browser directory is it possible to fetch this real-time data directly from the file in my browser’s directory? If so, how can I access and extract this data.
I'm trying to find a simple way to extract this real-time data from the browser’s storage files and be able to monitor it.

https://blog.logrocket.com/localstorage-javascript-complete-guide/#where-localstorage-stored ... Not sure if the sqlite file needs special credentials, or not, I've never tried opening to view the contents.
